Is a pseudo R squared of glmmTMB poisson model = 1 possible/does it make sense?
I'm running a number of glmmTMB models on animal behaviour data. For 2 of them, the pseudo R2 are 1 or essentially 1. In my understanding that would mean that the model explains the variance in the data perfectly. And that seems unrealistic to me. There is no way, I captured all variables that influence the behaviour of the focal animal.
About my data:
The models are based on similar data. Essentially, I check if animals make use of opportunities they encounter on a daily basis. So my data is Day, Animal ID, Animal Age, encountered opportunity, hours of availability, property 1 of opportunity, property 2 of opportunity, nr of times opportunity was used (could be 0).
For example, on day 1, bird A (0.5 years old) comes by a feeding tree C, which has properties X and Y. Bird A spends 2h around the feeding tree C and feeds on it 3 times (nr of times opportunity used). Nr of opportunities varies per day, hours of availability has to be >0, nr of times opportunity used can be 0. Properties can't be 0. We want to see how age and the properties affect opportunity use.
About the model:
I'm running a poisson model with a quadratic term with glmmTMB in R of the following structure:
all continuous variables are z_transformed
model <- glmmTMB( data=data, NrOppUsed ~ (age + age_squared) + prop1 + 
                     prop2 + (1|Animal ID) + (1|Animal ID nested in Day), 
           offset=log(hours of availability), family=poisson(link="log") )

R2:
I'm using the function r.squaredGLMM because I would like to get a measure of effect.
As a first step I would appreciate to understand, if a R2 of 1 can make sense or if there is an effect of glmmTMB on this that I'm not aware of.
edit:
this is the model output for one of the models which has only one property variable:
> summary(pois)
 Family: poisson  ( log )
Formula:          oppuse ~ (age_z + age_z2) * prop1 + (1 | FollowNr)
Data: mydata
 Offset: log(OpportunitiesH)

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   690.0    732.5   -335.0    670.0      509 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 FollowNr (Intercept) 0.9561   0.9778  
Number of obs: 519, groups:  FollowNr, 252

Conditional model:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)      -3.85404    0.41505  -9.286  < 2e-16 ***
age_z            -0.55049    0.62194  -0.885   0.3761    
age_z2            0.09125    0.27845   0.328   0.7431    
prop1AM         -25.67345   14.87040  -1.726   0.0843 .  
prop1O            2.65656    0.43172   6.153 7.58e-10 ***
age_z:prop1AM  -119.54493   66.23843  -1.805   0.0711 .  
age_z:prop1O     -1.21462    0.74712  -1.626   0.1040    
age_z2:prop1AM -125.25394   73.19725  -1.711   0.0870 .  
age_z2:prop1O    -1.43462    0.56042  -2.560   0.0105 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

this is the pseudo R2:
                R2m       R2c
delta     0.9997671 0.9998367
lognormal 0.9998446 0.9999143
trigamma  0.9994932 0.9995628

I checked for complexity, overdispersion, singularity, colinearity, distribution of residuals with DHARMA, all of this is fine.
For the above model, 60 random effect levels only had 1 observation, 117 had 2, and 75 had 3. I realize this might not be enough. I had picked this one instead of focal (see below), as I wanted to capture both individual variation, and also individual variation between days.
Below is the same model, but with focal individual instead of followNr (focal per date) as random effect. All random effect levels have a minimum of 8 observations (mean 19.2). The R2 is about the same.
 Family: poisson  ( log )
Formula:          oppuse ~ (age_z + age_z2) * prop1 + (1 | focalID)
Data: mydata
 Offset: log(OpportunitiesH)

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   774.6    817.2   -377.3    754.6      509 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups  Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 focalID (Intercept) 0.1303   0.361   
Number of obs: 519, groups:  focalID, 27

Conditional model:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)      -3.45906    0.40447  -8.552  < 2e-16 ***
age_z            -0.55328    0.61711  -0.897  0.36995    
age_z2            0.08578    0.27888   0.308  0.75839    
prop1AM         -22.36959   13.38108  -1.672  0.09458 .  
prop1O            2.73779    0.42986   6.369  1.9e-10 ***
age_z:prop1AM  -102.86447   59.18394  -1.738  0.08220 .  
age_z:prop1O     -1.27496    0.75381  -1.691  0.09077 .  
age_z2:prop1AM -105.81302   65.08490  -1.626  0.10400    
age_z2:prop1O    -1.66943    0.55277  -3.020  0.00253 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

                R2m       R2c
delta     0.9997650 0.9997781
lognormal 0.9998698 0.9998829
trigamma  0.9993991 0.9994122
```


This can happen if the model is overfit in a way that matches your current data almost perfectly while not working well at all on new data. That's typically when you have a very small number of observations relative to the number of coefficients that your model needs to fit. Please provide more information about the size and nature of your data and some snippets (at least) of your model summaries. If you place a block of a model's text summary between two lines each starting with"```" then it will be formatted properly; see what I did with your model formula for a guide.

Hello, thank you for your quick reply. I do have relatively many observations per estimated term (as far as I understand). A calculation like below yields values above 160 or 170, depending on my models.
length(residuals(model))/(length(fixef(model))+             nrow(as.data.frame(summary(model)$varCorr)))


Thanks for that info. To get useful advice, I think that you'll need to show, for one illustrative example, a summary of the result of your glmmTMB() model (formatted between lines starting with "```"), the specific code you used to call r.squaredGLMM(), and the output from r.squaredGLMM().

The summary helps. What's the distribution of observation numbers among your 252 FollowNr IDs? On the average there's about 2 observations per FollowNr (519/252) but I wonder whether a large proportion of FollowNr might only have had 1 observation. Also, since the question is about an apparently unrealistic r.squaredGLMM() result, please further edit to show the call to that function and its result.

Thank you very much for the kind help. I added more info, as you suggested.

Have you accounted for overdispersion yet? (Deviance/df.resid ~ 1.5; this is high although not insanely high ...)

No, I have not. I checked for overdispersion (with performance and DHARMA) and neither the tests nor residual distribution showed a problem. How do I know if I need to account for overdispersion and how would I do it then? I'm only aware of OLRE as a way when the model is clearly overdispersed, but that doesn't seem to be the case?

In these data, were there ever any non-0 oppuse outcomes when prop1 was at the level of AM? Based on the modeled coefficients, the oppuse (per hour, it seems) is already predicted to be pretty low when age=1, and the massively negative coefficients (in log scale) associated with prop1AM (both individually and in its two interaction terms) lead to a predicted oppuse evidently indistinguishable from 0. How many observations had prop1 at the level of AM?

There are 113 total observations for AM, and only 7 of them were used/had a non-0 outcome. Around age=1, they would be essentially zero, yes.

I wanted to answer my own question, as in the meantime, we have realized that the issue seems to lie with the way R2 is calculated for glmmTMB with MuMin.
We ran the same models as Bayesian GLMMS with the brm function of the brms package, so we could use the Bayesian R2 (function bayes_R2). The Bayesian models have very similar model estimates etc.
The R2 is no longer 1 or close to 1, but around 0.3 for fixed effects and 0.6 for the whole model. These values are way closer to what we would have expected and this suggests that the issue does not lie with our data or models, but seems to stem from the MuMin R2 calculation.
Best

I don't know much about how r.squaredGLMM() generates pseudo-$R^2$ values for this type of model. That said, it's possible that your fixed effects are capturing almost all of the explainable variability in your data (beyond the variance = mean around predictions of a Poisson model). It's hard to know without seeing the details, so look carefully at the combined distributions of ages and prop1 in the data. Look carefully at predictions from the model consistent with those distributions, e.g. with emmeans, and see how those line up with the "opportunity use" outcomes that you observed.
The 3 levels of prop1 have substantially different outcome estimates at the reference condition of age_z=0 (z-transformed age). In terms of the counts per hour predicted by the second model at a random effect of 0:
exp(-3.45906) ## for reference level of prop1
# [1] 0.03145932
exp(-3.45906-22.36959) ## for prop1=AM 
# [1] 6.064009e-12
exp(-3.45906+2.73779) ## for prop1=O 
# [1] 0.4861345

At that mean age (age_z=0) you have one level of prop1 that has a low but appreciable probability (0.03) of an "opportunity use" in an hour, another with 0 probability (prop1AM), and another (prop1O) with about a 50% chance. Those are pretty big differences associated with the levels of prop1. If most of your observed age values were near the mean, then that explains a lot.
The 2 very large magnitude interaction terms involving age and prop1AM will allow some "opportunity uses" for prop1AM at ages below the mean, as you observed in 7 out of 113 total prop1AM observations (according to a comment). It's harder to say what's going on with prop1O or with the reference level of prop1 at other ages, but close attention to the details of observations and model predictions might be informative.

Thank you very much for the help and your assessment!
